# Ping duration between requests in a website

Tags: web, ping

Let's say I have two requests, what's the minimum duration between them so that a big website won't consider me as a bot?

Here I am making a request and request is resolved around 150ms to 250ms because I'm downloading the page. The following request comes 200ms after my first request has been downloaded. Making a total of around 400ms time, would this be considered as a bot?

[image: example]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related with programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have a http-header called User-Agent, where (honest) bots should tell the server "hey I'm a bot", of course there are crawlers and bots which do not identify themselves as bots, but those are the ones we are trying to catch. Using many different methods. Exactly which methods are in use on your target, only the sysadmin in charge of that target can answer.

I would go the honest way, and identify myself as a bot, but I would check the robots.txt file for crawl rate limit, and respect it.

Honest bots is usually not a problem, dishonest bots are.